# Returning reference type passed to method

Tags: code-quality, readability

I'm asking this from .NET (C#) point-of-view, however, I'd preferire language agnostic answer.

Is it better to return the reference type when some value is changed in method or not? I'm mostly  concerned about readability, but I'd like to here others pros & cons if there are any.

For Example, we have the following structure

```
struct PersonInformation
{
    internal string name;
    internal int year;
}
```

Example 1:

```
private void Caller()
{
    var person = new PersonInformation;
    person = GetPersonInfo(person);
}

private PersonalInformation GetPersonInfo(PersonalInformation person)
{
     person.name = "Mike";
     person.year = 19;
     return person;
}
```

Example 2:

```
private void Caller()
{
    var person = new PersonInformation;
    GetPersonName(person);
}

private void GetPersonInfo(PersonalInformation person)
{
        person.name = "Mike";
        person.year = 19;

}
```

Comment: I prefer returning `void` because it makes it clear a side effect is happening. But I'd prefer even more not to have side effects in the first place.

Comment: Well, a method that changed `Person` would not be named `GetPersonInfo`, and returning a new `Person` might be part of a larger immutable strategy, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it better to return the reference type when some value is changed in method or not?

To expand on Doval's comment, it's ***far*** better to not cause side effects at all. Side effects make your code harder to reason about. They make your code harder to reuse. They make your code harder to test. They make it *way* harder to use concurrently.

These examples have their own problems. If your function is named `GetPersonInfo` why is it not returning anything - I mean to get something, you necessarily need to return it. For the other signature, why are you calling `GetPersonInfo` when you *already have a person info*? Both of these signatures are uncommon in C# (and other languages) because they don't follow the principle of least surprise. Programmers cannot simply look at the signature and reasonably guess what is going on. That leads to slowness writing code and it leads to bugs.

No, a better option would be to pass in some data to find the person you want and return (an ideally immutable) instance of person info.

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer to follow the [**Command-Query Separation Principle**](http://abdullin.com/command-query-separation/). The principle states that if you change information it is a **Command**, and then it returns nothing.

If the method call is a **Query**, it basically retrieves information and it should return with the correct type.

If you are retrieving the information of the person, the getPersonInfo() name is ok, but maybe you should pass the details of what person are you getting. For example

> db.getPersonInfoByName("Mike");

Following the CQS, the signature of *getPersonInfoByname* should return *PersonInformation*.

In the case you would like to change the age of the person, you would have a method which returns void because it changes information.

> void setBirthDate(date birthDate)

**TL;DR**

> Is it better to return the reference type when some value is changed
>   in method or not?

When changing values no reference type should be returned according to the Command-Query Separation Principle. If a function has side-effects, return void.

This allows a programmer to immediately recognize which functions contains side-effect and which does not.

Comment: How would you handle a function that accepts an object and returns a copy of that object with some fields modified?

Comment: If you follow strictly Command Query Separation, no such method could exist. I believe what you describe fits more in a Functional Programming Paradigm.

Comment: I wouldn't take the Command-Query Separation Principle too seriously. In any case where you're unconditionally doing something potentially destructive, the caller may want to know whether a change occurred or what old information was discarded, and you can usually get this information "for free" in the process of doing the update. For example, when inserting into a set or map.

Comment: @Doval, that is exactly one of the exceptions for the CQS Principle. Another example is Stack pop() method, which returns a value and changes the Stack. In the case it seemed more related to a regular application in which you can follow the principle.

Answer (score 1):

I think that having a void (mutator) method that starts with "Get" is a code smell on its own. Method names must be clear, descriptive and trustworthy. Your first example is better than the second one, however, I would not call it a good method.